# How to query firestore documents fields using a future forloop in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a future forloop to loop through firestore document base on a specific field but I can only target the document itself and it is printing the instance of the document. Here is my code:

```
  final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('userPhones')
    .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection("phoneNumbers")
    .get();

List list = [];
await Future.forEach(querySnapshot.docs, (element) async {
  String phoneNumber = element['number'];  // this line is not working
  list.add(phoneNumber);
  print(element); // this line prints out the instance of the document which isnt what isnt what I want
});
```

Comment: Did you try ```element.data()```? Try printing this and if your element data is printed then store ```element.data``` in a variable and use it get values.

Comment: I don't see why this needs a `Future.forEach` call, as all code inside the callback is synchronous as far as I can see.